# Почему вместо русских символов выводятся кракозябры (знаки вопросов в черных ромбиках)?

Tags: php, массивы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-32">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     $letters = range("a", "c");
     $nums = range(1, 3);
     $matrix = array("Буква" => $letters, "Цифра" => $nums);

     foreach ($matrix as $array => $list) {
         echo "<ul>";
         foreach ($list as $key => $value) echo "<li>$array[$key] = $value</li>";
         echo "</ul>";
     }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Вместо вывода "Буква" и "Цифра" выводится знак вопроса в черном ромбе. Как это исправить?

Comment: Вам действительно нужна кодировка `UTF-32`? В последнее время общепринято использовать `UTF-8`, а сам файл должен быть сохранён в формате `UTF-8 без BOM`.

Comment: Да никому она не нужна, просто автор вопроса пишет на пыхтоне, и не знает,  что надо использовать ютф-8.

Comment: Вам же сегодня уже отвечали по поводу перебора строки как массива.

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов изначально я написал UTF-8, но с ней не работало. Решил начать выставлять другие UTF-кодировки (мне так советовали делать, но это не работает :/). Вообщем я забыл поставить обратно utf-8 и отправил с utf-32.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk нет, я пишу на C++ )) Почему я отправил вопрос с кодировкой utf-32, а не utf-8 я уже сказал Рустаму Гимранову

Comment: @JustLearn  Учусь писать != Пишу

Comment: @JustLearn вопрос не в способе, а в принципе. С ЛЮБОЙ многобайтовой кодировкй обращение к строке как к массиву ведет к глюкам. Если для вас принципиально важно работать со строкой именно так, то используйте однобайтовую кодировку, windows-1251, cp866, KOI8-R. UTF - это многобайтовая кодировка

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Ваш совет не помог

Comment: Ничей совет мне не помог))

Comment: Все равно выводит знаки вопроса